# What is the complexity of index for lists of lists(e.g. list[x][y])

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python

```
lst = [[1,2,3...],[4,5,6...]]
```

Assume I have a list whose length is`n` and each nested list has the same length.
So I want to use `lst[x][y]` to find some element.
what is the complexity of it?
I tried to google it but not find answers.

Edited:Thanks guys! So if I input a list containing n lists (each containing n elements), then how many times do I index the list (in terms of n)? Is it 2n?

Answer (score 3):

Time complexity of Python data structures are documented here:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

The one you're asking about is "Get Item" for `list`, and it's *O(1)*. Even though you index a list and a nested list, that's still *O(1)*.

Comment: Thanks! So if I input a list containing n lists (each containing n elements), then how many times do I index the list (in terms of n)? Is it 2n?

Comment: This is independent of n (i.e., it will not be any slower when the lists are larger).  It is just 2 "get item" operations.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing is an **O(1)** operation (constant time).  Thus, two successive indexing operations is still **O(1)**.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) shows that "get item" is `O(1)`. To analyze an expression like `l[x][y]` it might be helpful to break it into its components:

```
temp = l[x]
temp[y]
```

When analyzing sequential operations, we add the time complexity. So this is `O(1) + O(1)`. But this simplifies to just `O(1)`.